# AWS S3 upload in chunking mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, esp32, sigv4

I am trying to implement upload to S3 using chunking mode: [Link Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html)

I do not understand exactly how it should be implemented from client prespective? For the example in the link (64k, 1k, 0k chunks) will it be 3 different PUT requests? If yes would each request have differnt 'Authorization' header? If no, how do I get confirmation for each chunk?

If someone has example on how to do that in C / C++ (Arduino) it would be great.

Thank you

Comment: is there no abstractions available in the SDK?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No, there is no supported SDK for Arduino for ESP32

Comment: The example given is one PUT request, with three chunks, the first includes the HTTP header, the next two chunks are sent as is, without any header other than the length and signature.  You only get the single reply to the HTTP PUT request after you've sent the zero-byte final chunk and you're done (well, it can fail early, I suppose)